# How to connect door nodes using a polyline

Tags: cartography, indoor

I am working on an indoor positioning project which need to transform CAD drawings to GIS shape files. I have transformed the file from CAD to ArcMap 10.1 already.

My current problem is that how could I transform the doors in CAD to a set of polyline to as an independent layer. Currently, a door is consisted of a arc and a line but the connected line (door sill) is actually what I want.

I want to know is there any simple geo-spatial method to do that. Hopefully it will not use programming because of limited deadline. I am sorry I cannot upload the picture at this stage.

Comment: Are you just wanting to save the lines representing sills as a separate layer?  In which case just select by attributes to get the sills (I presume they have some identification) and then save the selection to a new shapefile (see: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000000p000000).  If this isn't the issue, please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.